# open sphere around $x=14$ with radius $r=3$ for closed set $[10,16] \cup [17,25]$, is $16$ an interior point?

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, metric-spaces

Let $ S=[10,16] \cup [17,25] \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ and
$ d: \mathbb{R}^n \times \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R} $ with $ \mathbb{R}: d(x, y)=|x-y| $.

I need to find the **open** sphere around $x=14$ with radius $r=3$

$B_3(14)=\{y \in S| |14-y|<3\} =(11,16)$ or is $16$ an interior point?

Comment: Are you familiar with the subspace topology?

Comment: No, we haven't had the topic of topologies yet

Comment: Yes.  For any metric space:  every point in an open sphere is an interior point of that sphere.  In particular, $16$ is an interior point of $B_3(14)$ in the metric space $S$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an answer without (explicitly using) the subspace topology.

Recall that in a metric space $M$, a subspace $C$ is closed if and only if every convergent sequence inside of $C$ has its limit in $C$. A subspace $U$ is open if and only if $M \setminus U$ is closed.

So to show that $B_3(14)$ is open in $S$, we should show that $S \setminus B_3(14)$ is closed. To see this, let $(x_n)$ have a limit $x$ in $S$, so that each $x_n \notin B_3(14)$. Then $|x_n-14| \geq 3$ for each $n \geq 1$. As distance is continuous, it follows that $|x-14| \geq 3$, so $x \notin B_3(14)$, thus $S \setminus B_3(14)$ is closed, hence $B_3(14)$ is open.

Answer (score 1):

Recall the definition of the subspace topology (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology).

**Definition** Let $(X,\tau)$ be a topological space and let $S \subseteq X$ be a subset. Then we define the subspace topology as
$$\tau_S = \{S\cap U\: |\: U \in \tau\}.$$
That is, a subset of $S$ is open if it is the intersection of $S$ with an open subset of $X$.

In your question we have $X = \mathbb{R}$ equipped with the standard topology, that is the topology generated by open balls. Let's denote the open ball of radius $3$ centered at $14$ in $\mathbb{R}$ by $B_3(14)=\{x\in \mathbb{R} \: | \: |x-14| <3\}$.
Then the ball of radius $3$ centered at $14$ in $S$, which we denote by $B_3^S(14)$, is the intersection of $S$ and $B_3(14)$, that is $$B_3^S(14) = B_3(14) \cap S = \{x\in S \: | \: |x-14| <3\} = (11,16].$$
Notice that this set is open by definition of subspace topology, being the intersection of $S$ with an open set.